# Easiest way to build and distribute Excel UDF add-in capable of Statistical Analysis

Tags: c++, python, excel

**01 - BACKGROUND:**

I'm a typical non-programmer R user for 6+ years. Which means:
i) I`m comfortable with the language most of the time and have written R packages for myself, but
ii) writing C++ code (Rcpp) is not something I've done
iii) R is fast enough for my purposes and data size

**02 - PROBLEM STATEMENT:**
Few months ago I started at a new company where my peers do not use R/Python, only MS-Excel. I want to share my statistical analyses/workflow with them.

**03 - WHAT I TRIED, AND POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS:**

- **First** option that came to mind was to **write a simple UDF library in pure VBA** (.xlam). It's easy to distribute and update, since everyone has Excel/VBA installed in their machines. I've started to work down this road **BUT found myself reinventing the wheel** for very basic tasks (fit a few distributions to data, eg.), and limited by the VBA capabilities on data analysis. Something similar to what I would like to accomplish would be: https://www.real-statistics.com/ + our own analysis workflow.
  **Conclusion:** I understand *it will be (very) hard to re-write* all the routines I used to do in R in a vba-xlam.
- **Second** **option** : PyXLL. Nope; peers won't install Python on their machines.
- **Third** **option**: ask peers to install two Excel addins: MyLibrary.xlam and [QuantLibXL](https://www.quantlib.org/quantlibxl/) to harness the power of Quantlib on statistics and use some VBA to put everything together. I haven't tried this since it seems that QuantLib is really focused on *pricing* derivatives and I will still have to write huge VBA code to fit a Log-Logistic distribution to data on a spreadsheet, for example. Something that is a one-liner in R.
- **Fourth option**: bite the bullet and learn C++. Read a book on XLL development [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470027975) and build the XLL add-in using statistical libraries made on/for C++. Easy distribution, also free to build, **BUT dive in a whole new universe** that I can find hard to navigate (real programming, not R scripting).
- **Fifth Option**: Use [Excel-DNA](https://excel-dna.net/)  to write my library in VB.Net ([so I can use things like Accord.NET](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Distributions)). Easier than (fourth) because VB.Net easier than learning C++ ?

**04 - MY QUESTIONS**

- 1/ Am I missing any obvious alternative here ?
- 2/ Which of the options above would you suggest and why ?

**05 - SUPPORTING MATERIAL**

- [This is a great](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10429/free-and-tested-optimization-statistical-and-visualization-packages-for-c/10435#10435) thorough answer from 2014 and somewhat related to the above. Yes, I've done my homework and read about all of the options before asking.
- I am aware of [Deriscope](https://www.deriscope.com/freedownload.php). Seems overkill compared to what I want to accomplish (a library of ~50 functions that will make analyses faster in our department). Plus I'll be dependent on a third-party solution.

Comment: If someone could please add the appropriate tags, I'd appreciate it. New user with limited privileges here.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328608/easiest-way-to-build-and-distribute-excel-udf-add-in-capable-of-statistical-anal "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Thanks @gnat. What do you suggest then? Leave this question here or on overflow ?

Comment: "it will be (very) hard to re-write all the routines I used to do in R" - true, but if you decide to go the "build the library myself" path, if you investigate a bit more, it may turn out that, in practice, there's a small subset of routines that your team would use something like 70-80% of the time. If you can identify what those are, you can start by implementing only those few and get most of the benefit. Maybe you can also build on top of (or just call into) another library like the real-statistics one you mentioned.

Comment: Excel.DNA does not restrict you to VB.Net, you can also use C#, F#, or use these languages to utilize [R.Net](https://coders-corner.net/2015/11/01/use-r-in-c/) as a bridge to R.  (and there is no such thing as VBA.Net, VB.Net is a language comparable to C#, not some toy language). I have used Excel.DNA for several applications for myself, and can recommend it, it is definitely the approach I would try if I were in your shoes.

Comment: Thanks @FilipMilovanović. That is where I'm at right now; some of the UDFs written and a few that I can't either because I do not know how to implement or if it's possible to (fitting a distribution on data through MLE, for example). I agree with your suggestion on "low hanging fruits" though. Much appreciated

Comment: ... however, the C++ road would definitely be overkill.

Comment: @DocBrown, many thanks on the opinion on C++.  That is what I'm thinking right now. It would a lot of investment to learn C++ and how to make a XLL only to  write 50-70 Functions. Would you say VB.Net could be an adequate route for this case ?

Comment: @Dan: as I said, I would use Excel.DNA. If you use VB.Net or C# with Excel.DNA is more or less a matter of taste. If you know VBA already, the learning curve for VB.Net may be less steep. For statistical analysis you will definitely need an additional component, probably one of those listed at the Q&A from 2014 you already linked to.

Comment: You should add BERT, the Basic Excel R Toolkit to your list of options:
https://bert-toolkit.com/ and https://github.com/sdllc/Basic-Excel-R-Toolkit/issues.

Comment: @Dan: I don't think the bounty will bring you any better recommendations, especially the last one by Govert, the author of Excel.DNA, looks very promising. Note that software and tool recommendations are off-topic for this site, I was actually astonished that the question was not closed and deleted by the community (maybe because you avoided directly to ask for a tool).

Answer (score 3):

You can [install BERT](https://bert-toolkit.com/bert-quick-start) as an add-in in Excel. Then in Excel you can enter the R console for basic coding and debugging. And for the clients, you wrap your R function into a new file saved to the startup folder, so BERT can load all the functions from there, and clients can choose whatever they want in Excel directly.

```
customized_function <- function(data){
  ## Your original R code
}
```

Other than that, your second option on PyXLL should work.

> peers won't install Python on their machines.

According to their [doc](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/distribution.html#deploying-the-python-environment), to deploy the Python environment people don't have to install Python locally, instead, you can take a Python environment and copy it to a network drive and have PyXLL reference it from there.

Another option is to use their [pyxll-installer](https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-installer) as the Python runtime is bundled with PyXLL into a single standalone installer instead.